# Groovy way for HTTPS request with client authentification

Tags: authentication, groovy, ssl-certificate

Is there a Groovy way to open a SSL connection to a server with client side authentification without using the JVM keystore?

I want to enable users to upload a public key over a website and then access a REST API on their server in a secure way. So I can have a lot of different keys which have to be loaded during runtime. I don't know if this is even possible using keystores.

I am looking for a solution, where I can just provide the keystring on connection initialization.